# Getting "javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress" in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-transactions, pessimistic-locking

I am using JPA+Hibernate in my Spring Boot Application. My Service Method is as follows:-

```
    @Override
    public Employee createEmployee(Employee employeeModel) {
        logger.debug("entered the createEmployee method");
        Optional<Employee> optionalEmployee = repository.findByEmpShortNm(employeeModel.getEmpShortNm());
        logger.debug("Fetched the optional");
        if(optionalEmployee.isPresent())
            return optionalEmployee.get();
        else {
            logger.debug("Persisting employee.....");
            return repository.save(employeeModel);
        }
    }
```

**EmployeeRepository.java** has following method:-

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Optional<Employee> findByEmpShortNm(String uuid);
```

My Application was working fine until I applied `Lock annotation` on my repository method. After applying `Lock` createEmployee method is throwing following exception:-

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1560)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1581)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
```

Why it's not able to get a transaction while it was working fine when I was not using `@Lock` Annoation. What's the relation b/w @Lock and Transaction.

I would appreciate if any reference can be provided.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: you should annotate your service with `@Transactional`

> When the lock is explicitly enabled and there is no active
> transaction, the underlying JPA implementation will throw a
> TransactionRequiredException.

It is somehow logical when you don't have your own transaction, why do you want to lock the entity object? You should have a transaction outside repository method during which, you want to lock entity object.

Read this article:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-transaction-locks

Comment: does it mean that when we are not doing explicit lock, transaction is automatically created by JPA/Hibernate but when we are marking explicit locking we should mark with Transactional to create Transaction.

Comment: then Transactional annotation can also be applied on the same Repository method because transaction is required for do the db thing. right ?

Comment: I've just added some notes to my answer, please read it again and let me know if you have any question.